# How to send data to the previous view controller swift

Tags: swift

in my app, an admin can create a group and filter people willing to enter this group in asking a question. So during the group creation I need to send data back to the previous view controller. These data are the questions created by the admin. I don't manage to send these data to the previous VC despite my several trials

1- On the First view controller, click on "choose privacy" button to open action sheet
2- choose "filtered by admin" on action sheet to perform the segue toward the second view controller
3- Write questions on the Text View , click on "Save" Button to save questions and going back to the previous view controller

I used delegates and protocols without success. When I go back to the first VC , it prints "empty questions".

Thanks for your help .

First screen:

```
protocol getQuestions {
    func catchQuestions(string: String)
}

class NewGroupViewController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate,getQuestions {\
    var questions = ""

    func catchQuestions(string: String) {
        print(string)
        questions = string
    }
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        if self.questions == "" {
            savedGroupLabel.text = ""
            print("empty question")
        }
        else {
            print(" the question is \(self.questions)")
            savedGroupLabel.text = "questions saved !"
        }
    }

    func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) {
        guard let identifier = segue.identifier else {
            assertionFailure("Segue had no idientifier")
            return
        }
    
        if identifier == "toNewQuestion" {
            let secondvc = segue.destination as! NewQuestionVC
            secondvc.delegate = self
        }
    }
}
```

Second View Controller

```
class NewQuestionVC: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var questionTextView: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var saveButton: UIButton!
    
    var delegate : getQuestions?
    var questionString = "Questions people will have to answer before to be accepted in your group"
    var questions2 = ""

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        questionTextView.delegate = self
        questionTextView.text = questionString
    }

    @IBAction func PressSave(_ sender: Any) {
        saveButton.isEnabled = false
        self.questions2 = questionTextView.text
    
        if self.questions2 == "Questions people will have to answer before to be accepted in your group" || self.questions2 == "" {
            SPAlert.present(message: "Empty field" )
            saveButton.isEnabled = true
         }
         else {
             self.questions2 = questionTextView.text!
             print("\(self.questions2)")
        
             delegate?.catchQuestions(string: self.questions2)

             SPAlert.present(message: "Questions saved !" )

             self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
             self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: 1/ Make sure the `catchQuestion` run before `viewWillAppear`
2/ Why you have to call `dismiss` then `popViewController` on NewQuestionVC?

Comment: Thank you for your reply . You are right , I don't need to call dismiss . But how could I run "catchQuestion" before "viewWillAppear" ?  There is probably something that I did not understand completely with protocols

Comment: What do you get from the print in catchQuestions ? To make it clearer, change the print as: print("catches question: ", string)

Comment: I don't get anything from the print in catchQuestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the followings:

1. Please remove

```
self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

2. Please make sure `catchQuestions` is called before `viewWillAppear`, it should be. If not try using `viewDidAppear`.
3. `prepareForSegue` need to be `override`.

Comment: I removed self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil) and I changed viewWillAppear for viewDidAppear without success

Comment: Have you checked `catchQuestions` is called? And which function is called first, `catchQuestions` or `viewDidAppear`?

Comment: I think that catchQuestions is not called cause the print inside this function does not print anything.

Comment: `delegate?.catchQuestions(string: self.questions2)`
Please check if delegate is not nil, and also self.questions2 is not empty

Comment: I confirm that delegate is nill , but I also printed self.questions2 apart to try  and the variable contain what is expected

Comment: In `NewQuestionVC` `viewDidLoad` try to print or check if delegate is not nil. If it is nil you have to check `prepareForSegue` in previous view controller which present `NewQuestionVC`. 
Also I notice that your `prepareForSeuge` need to have `override`. Please add and try again!

Comment: You are right !! prepareForSegue need to have override . I changed it for :  override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?){ .... }. Thank you very much for your help !

Comment: Please mark this as correct answer it could help other people :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to call both dismiss and popViewController.

In NewGroupViewController, viewWillAppear here gets called as soon as you call dismiss the current viewController, replacing it with viewDidAppear will probably do the trick and is the better approach as it gets called only after the viewController is shown.

Comment: I replaced viewWillAppear by viewDidAppear, without success